# convert IDictionary data into JSON string using NewtonJSON

Tags: c#, json.net

how can I convert `IDictionary` data into `JSON` using `NewtonJSON`.  My `IDictionary` data contains the following data:

```
type: 19
id  : 4433
```

Now I want to convert it into

```
{
  "type":"19",
  "id": "4433"
}
```

How do I do this?

```
  IDictionary<string, string> messageData = message.Data;

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageData, new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
                });
```

here is the update please see my screenshots
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.NET (formely `Newtonsoft.Json`) already has the built in capability to convert dictionaries into Json objects:

```
// the dictionary may be anything IDictionary<string, whatever>, Json.NET will convert it anyway
IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "type", "19" },
    { "id" ,"4433"}
};


var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
});
```

Outputs:

```
{
  "type": "19",
  "id": "4433"
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a562kK

**[Edit]**

The type you are trying to serialize [is **not** an `IDictionary`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Util.ArrayMap/) at all. You should try to convert it to a dictionary first.

Here an example (assuming `message.Data` implements at least `IEnumerable`):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var item in message.Data)
{
    // get Key and Value from item here
    var kvp = item as KeyValuePair<string, string>; // this is just an example, I do not know what type your message.Data is returning
    dict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}

// now you may serialize `dict`
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts but `IDictionary<string, string>` is getting returned and i use solution suggested by you then i am getting error `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` , i have updated my question

Comment: I do not understand what is your issue, if you have an `IDictionary<string, string>` than use that. The code works no matter what generic type you use in your dictionary.

Comment: @Hunt edited my answer, please be more clear on your requirements next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = d.Select(x => new obj{ type = x.Key, id = x.Value});     
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

Class:

```
public class obj
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set;}
}
```